# Unable to convert varchar to int in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to perform a query where I can convert a `varchar` to `INT` column in order to perform a calculation, however, I consistently get this error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '83640.00' to data type int

When I exclude this value from the query, then it simply shows the same error message with the next value in the table

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '57800.00' to data type int

The calculation I am trying to perform is simply the column `* 100 (Net_Value_NETWR * 100)`. `Net_Value_NETWR` is currently defined as `varchar` datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'57800.00'` is a `varchar` that represents a `decimal`, not an `int`. You cannot convert a `varchar` that represent a `decimal` directly to an `int`, you would have to convert it twice:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(int,CONVERT(decimal(7,2),'57800.00'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not store numbers in a string!  The canonical solution would be to use `try_convert()`.  But you actually want the value.  So, convert to a decimal, say:

```
select convert(decimal(10), Net_Value_NETWR)
```

or whatever column is mistakenly storing numbers in strings.

The conversion to `decimal` sidesteps the problem.  `decimal(10)` is big enough to store an integer, but it also allows decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

**Listen**

Here value is decimal, if you will convert the decimal value into integer then your will be change either you have to leave value after decimal or round of value.

Once you will convert '1234' string to integer then it will work fine.

Now its upto you what function you will use FLOOR(), or  CEILING()

```
CAST(FLOOR(yourField) as int), CAST(CEILING(yourField) as int)
```

CEILING will increase the value before deciaml by one and floor will return the exact value before decimal, and in both cases after decimal value will be remove.

Now you have only integer value then you can convert to integer without any error.